# Trying to remember the name of a series/book involving time

Tags: story-identification, time

A few years ago i read a book that involved time travel as one of the main plot elements. As of right now i can't quite place a finger on the name of the book.

## Details that I remember

- There were at least 2 books in the series
- The main character was boy and relatively young
- One main part of the book was a group called "The organization" or something similar
- At one point the main character sews the fabric of time back together
- There is some kind of "time train"

### Edit: The cover of the book looked somewhat steampunky

- There was a train that went across different layers of time, at one point in the book this train is blown up
- The Organization is HQ'd in a large and very tall tower
- A specific set of tools is used for weaving time
- At one point an executive is leaving the HQ in some form of Helicopter and is blown up.
- The book switches narrators at a few points
- I read the book about 5~ years ago but it was released before that point.
- If i recall correctly the main character was trained at some form of academy
- Not sure about this part, but the organizations role was to prevent time from tearing apart but there was a faction that wanted just that to happen
- The book is written in first person.

Comment: Has some elements of Thief of Time...

Comment: While searching for the book title this came up as well, unfortunately this isn't the book i'm looking for.

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Thief-Sacrifice-Kevin-C-Bennett-ebook/dp/B00YK3UFQW

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_End_of_Eternity

Comment: @Richard Thought you had it here, unfortunately i don't remember anything about Nazis being involved ;)

Comment: I also came across 'The End OF Eternity" during my searching, it doesn't seem to be the book i'm looking for.

Comment: Can I suggest you work your way through the questions here; http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/20774 and see if you can add any extra details.

Comment: @Richard I went thru the list like you suggested and managed to come with a few tidbits of information but as i read this book quite some time ago i drew a blank on most important details.

Comment: @AnnoyedAndCOnfused - It's a definite improvement. Can you add any extra detail about the main character; his name, his race, his purpose, where and how he was chosen?). Can you remember what the Organization was up to (policing time, repairing paradoxes?). Was this a book aimed at adults or young adults? How long ago was "a few years" 2, 5, 10?

Comment: @Richard More details about the organization added, it's all very slowly coming back to me. :)

Comment: For some reason, I'm wondering if the series in question is [**The Seems**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Seems)

Comment: @JeffZeitlin YES YES YES YES! This is it! I gave up on this website but you pulled thru THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Seriously well done, thank you so much

Comment: @AnnoyedAndCOnfused I've entered it as a formal answer below; I'd take it as a favor if you'd accept it by clicking the check next to it.

Comment: @Jubobs Thank you for editing my question into one with better structure and formatting, i'll do better the next time i submit a question here! <3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking my answer from my wild guess in the comments above, the series is [The Seems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Seems). A fun read, even if you're an adult.

> The series follows Becker Drane, a Fixer for a world called The Seems, which provides our world with resources such as Sleep, Time and Energy.
>   In the first book, Becker Drane must find and capture a Glitch wreaking havoc in the Department of Sleep. Glitches are creatures with three arms that are able to move very quickly, creating problems wherever they go. With the help of Briefer Simly Frye and Fixer Casey Lake, the three try to Fix this Glitch. After many challenges, Becker manages to find and capture the Glitch.
>
> In the second book, The Tide, using 50 trays of Frozen Moments, has managed to construct a Time Bomb which could cause unimaginable damage to both The World and The Seems. The Fixers are not able prevent the explosion, and Essence is spilled into the World. Becker Drane, Fixer #37, is sent in to recover the bomb, which could still be hazardous. Tom Jackal, Fixer #7, who was thought to be dead, Fixes the bomb but dies in the process. Becker also breaks the Golden Rule, which forbids anyone with access to a Case File for a person in The World to have contact with that person.
>
> In the third book, Becker is found guilty of breaking the Golden Rule by meeting with Jennifer Kaley at the end of The Split Second. Because of this, he is suspended from duty for a year, and his memories of Jennifer are "unremembered". Jennifer is also unremembered of everything about The Seems. However, before they are both unremembered, a train of Thought goes missing and Becker is called in with three other Fixers to find it. **The train is found**, and Becker must drive it back. However, all the extra Thought that The Seems had was spent already. To get The World the Thought it needs, Becker drives through to the Inbetweener. He succeeds in getting the Thought back, **but he crashes into the dangerously low entrance** and may not have survived. Jennifer receives a job in The Seems, but at Becker's request, she is still unremembered about Becker and The Seems.
>
> A fourth book, titled A Better Place, has been confirmed on the official website for the series. "Chapter Zero" of the book was made available to read in May 2012,[1] but as of July 2015, no release date or cover have been revealed. However, as of May 2015, the authors have continued to indicate that they are working on getting it released eventually.

Comment: done and done! Again, thank you so much you are a fantastic person.

Comment: @Jeff: I posted some text from the article, but it you could post or highlight the specific bits that match up to the question, that would probably be best. :)

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - Most of what matches the question is from memory when I read the books; about the only thing mentioned in the article that matches up with the question is the bit about the train. I've highlighted that in the quoted text above.